# How can I convert a nested json to a specific dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json which looks like this:

```json
"A":{"B":1,"C":[{"D":2,"E":3},{"D":6,"E":7}]}
```

I would like to create a dataframe based on this with two rows.

| B | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 |

In an imperative language, I would use a for loop. However, I saw that this is not recommended with Scala and therefore I am wondering how I can explode this inner JSON and use the entries in new rows.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_json` to parse the string json values :

```
val df = Seq(
  """"A":{"B":1,"C":[{"D":2,"E":3},{"D":6,"E":7}]}"""
).toDF("col")

val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "col",
    from_json(
      regexp_extract(col("col"), "\"A\":(.*)", 1), // extract the part after "A":
      lit("struct<B:int,C:array<struct<D:int,E:int>>>")
    )
  ).select(col("col.B"), expr("inline(col.C)"))


df1.show
//+---+---+---+
//|  B|  D|  E|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1|  2|  3|
//|  1|  6|  7|
//+---+---+---+
```

You can also pass the schema as StructType to `from_json` function which you define like this :

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("B", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("C", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("D", IntegerType, true),
            StructField("E", IntegerType, true)
          ))))
  )
)
```